# Establishing a date format

Tags: c#, string, date

I have created an app in which the user can select a date from a calendar and create an appointment based on that date.

I then proceed to show inside a datagridview, the information about the appointment but im having issues displaying the date.

The date shows like this: 20151117 (year, month, day, alltogether) and i want it to be like this: 17/11/2015

So i created a new string in which i divide those chars and i place "/" between them, the thing is im having a problem with the day, after finishing the string, once i show it up it looks like: 100/11/2015 and no mather what i do or how i try, the day chars will always look like 100, making little changes sometimes makes it vary between 100 or 97 for example.

Any ideas?

EDIT: This is how we are working with the dates:

```
            DataRow drEmpleado = dtEmpleados.Rows[empleado.SelectedIndex];
        string dia = calendario.SelectionStart.Day.ToString();
        if (dia.Length == 1)
            dia = "0" + dia;
        string mes = calendario.SelectionStart.Month.ToString();
        if (mes.Length == 1)
            mes = "0" + mes;
        string año = calendario.SelectionStart.Year.ToString();
        string fecha = año + mes + dia;
```

Comment: Are you not using `DateTime` objects?

Comment: `dataGridViewCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
this.date.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle;` not sure why you can't do something as simple as this.. also `Google` works wonders if you use it properly.

Comment: There, i added a piece of code to show how are we working with the dates, i believe as we are not using DateTime we cannot use the cellsytle.format, also i googled a lot, and i do now know all the properties that exists out there so how am i supposed to search for something i do not know, thats why im asking!!

Comment: @Lobialkon Why are you not using `DateTime`?

Comment: @DStanley Sorry but this is not something that i did, but ive been told to look out to lend a hand, and i believe its late to change it to DateTime as its saving the date as an integer on the database? its quite strange actually

Comment: @DStanley as its already done like that, i just wanted to work it as a string to give it a format, which works, but the day always shows like a 100+ number instead of the ones on the regular string

Comment: @Lobialkon Yes strange, indeed.  Although you will be making it _stranger_ by trying to format your dates manually.  I would see if you can't change the property to `DateTime`, even if it means going down a rabbit hole for a bit.  Sometimes when people have these legacy apps they don't take the time to step back and try to change things in a way that's painful at first but pays off in the long run.

Comment: Even if you "can't" use `DateTime` throughout the code, you could use `DateTime` to deal with the formatting (get a `DateTime` from the data you have then `.ToString(...)` with the format you want.

Comment: I'll give it a show with DateTime, although its going to take a lot of time and effort, still, i do wish to know why if i have a string that is 20151117 the last two chars work so strange, why instead of showing 17 when putting them together it shows 105

Comment: `var date = new DateTime(calendario.SelectionStart.Year, calendario.SelectionStart.Month, calendario.SelectionStart.Day).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");`

Comment: @Lobialkon You haven't shown how you are _currently_ trying to manitpulate the string, only how you convert it to a `yyyymmdd` format, so there's no way to tell why the day is getting messed up.

Answer (score 0):

[DataGridViewCellStyle.Format Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
YourDataGridView.Columns["Date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = @"dd/MM/yyyy";
```

your code is a bit overkill do something like this to get the value in the format of `17/11/2015`

```
var someDate2 = "20151117";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(someDate2, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` does not *have* a format.  You choose a format when you (or a display control) turns the value into a string.  So you need to see if the calendar control you are using has some sort of display format property that you can set, so that it displays the date the way you want it to.